# Does the kernel keep track of where a process starts in memory or does the CPU?

Tags: kernel, cpu, paging

I'm trying to implement paging in a simple kernel I'm writing. I understand page directories and page tables and how to map memory from a virtual address to a physical address. I've implemented these concepts in my kernel already. The part I don't understand is if the kernel should keep track of where each program starts in memory (by a page offset) or if the CPU handles this. If the CPU handles it is this what a TSS is for? Thanks.

Comment: The kernel must keep a record of the pages mapped by a process (including the one mapped during the process loading). The TSS is needed for some protection mechanisms (e.g. stack switching) and was primarily an attempt at an hw assisted context switching but it was never used in this second form by the mainstream OSes (due to portability, that's also why pages are usually also kept in OS specific tables)

Comment: But if I have two processes lets say process 1 virtual memory address 0x0 is mapped to physical address 0xc0000 and process 2 virtual memory address 0x0 is mapped to physical address 0xd0000. These addresses are translated by the cpu right? So how does the cpu make the distinction between process 1 memory address 0 and process 2 memory address 0?

Comment: The CPU uses translation tables and the OS, before jumping to a process' code, set the relevant table as "active"/"current". Remember: one CPU can execute only a single program at a given instant (see concurrent vs parallel), so only one virtual memory configuration is active at a given instant. The OS set this and that table based on the unique process running in the CPU at the given instant.

Comment: Ahhh that makes much more sense. Thank you.